# Angular - How to fix an "Object is possibly 'null'" error from the component's template

Tags: html, angular, angular11

I am working on an e-commerce Angular 11 application.

I have a template that has to render an error message if the *quantity provided* for a cart item *is less than 1*.

The `cartItem` can be `null` (or `undefined`) and I can't (or am not allowed to) change that, since it comes like this from the back-end.

As a result, I get an

> Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.ngtsc(2533)

error.

I attempted to fix the problem in the template, this way:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="cartItem?.qty !== null && cartItem?.qty !== undefined">
    <app-alert *ngIf="cartItem?.qty < 1"
    type="error"
    [dismissible]='false'>
    You have to specify a quantity of at least one 
    </app-alert>
</ng-container>
```

I was expecting this to work, but it does not.

##### What is a viable solution to this problem?

Comment: Why is the `ngIf` about `qty`, if it's `cartItem` that may be `null`/`undefined`? That could be affecting the type narrowing that's applied. I'd be more direct: `*ngIf="cartItem != null"` (note `!=`, not `!==`, so it handles both `null` and `undefined`) or `*ngIf="cartItem ?? null !== null"` (also handles both, but possibly less likely someone will come along later and "tut" at that `!=` replacing it with `!==` -- and introducing a bug).

Comment: (Side note: I'm going to assume `qty` is of type `number`. If so, `cartItem?.qty` will never be `null`, not even if `cartItem` is `null`. `cartItem?.qty` will evaluate to `undefined` if `cartItem` is either `null` or `undefined`. The only way it could be `null` is if `cartItem` is not `null` or `undefined`, but `cartItem.qty` is `null`.)

Comment: What code does the error relate to? The `ngIf` on `ng-container`, or the one on `app-alert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here

```
<app-alert *ngIf="cartItem?.qty < 1"
```

The compiler will warn that `cartItem` is possibly `null` while you didn't handle the `null` or `undefined` case when comparing with the value (in the current element).

While you have done the `null` and `undefined` check (at the top level), you can remove the `?` from `cartItem.qty` in `<app-alert>` element.

You can simplify as:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="cartItem?.qty">
    <app-alert *ngIf="cartItem.qty < 1"
    type="error"
    [dismissible]='false'>
    You have to specify a quantity of at least one 
    </app-alert>
</ng-container>
```

Or

```
<ng-container *ngIf="cartItem && cartItem.qty">
    <app-alert *ngIf="cartItem.qty < 1"
    type="error"
    [dismissible]='false'>
    You have to specify a quantity of at least one 
    </app-alert>
</ng-container>
```